# Java getNetworkInterfaces() not working on Debian 9

Tags: java, linux, debian

The following java code used to return all my network interfaces.

```
public class InterfaceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        int i=0;
        while (networkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface nextElement = networkInterfaces.nextElement();
            System.out.println(nextElement.getName());
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(i+" interfaces found!");
    }    
}
```

Display something like:

```
lo
eth0
wlan0
waln1
3 interfaces found!
```

But now it only returns

```
wired
lo
2 interfaces found!
```

Note: I renamed my network card to wired, by specifying it on /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules (replacing the mac address by the real one)

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="**00:00:00:00:00:00**", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="wired"
```

However, I also have two usb WiFi dongles which I can see when I type **ifconfig -a**.

So, what could be causing java not to see the other network interfaces (two USB WiFi dongles)?

Thanks in advance for any help.